# How to change default cpi for `lp`?

Tags: printing, cups, lp

I know I can change the characters per inch used by `lp` with `lp -o cpi=12` (or any number you like). But is it possible to change the default value of this option globally? The default, when `-o cpi=<N>` is not passed, is `10`. But I'd like to change this default number to something else so that I do not have to type `-o cpi=<mynumber>` always and in all scripts I wrote in the past. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `lpoptions` command.

That writes settings to `~/.cups/lpoptions` or, if run as root, in the system-wide `/etc/cups/lpoptions` file.

These settings are used when submitting jobs via `lp` or `lpr`, hence changes take effect immediately without the need to restart services.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to restart any services after changing something?

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide that info

Comment: I used `lpoptions -o cpi=12` as root (file was altered according, I checked) followed by `lp`. But this did not work (it used default cpi, so `10`), however when I do `lp -o cpi=12` it corretly uses `12`.

Comment: I just did `lpoptions`, which lists the correct settings (changed `cpi`), but when I do `lpoptions -p <myprinter>` then I do not get any `cpi` settings (it just says `none`). Do I have to use `lpoptions` printer-specific? I'd like to set it globally for all installed printers.

Comment: Should the changes made with `lpoptions` also appear in `printers.conf`? (They don't for me)

Comment: I just tried it locally and for me it did work (`lpoptions -o cpi=12; lpr testfile; lpoptions -o cpi=10; lpr otherfile`). Note that your `~/.cups/lpoptions` file, if it exists, overrides the global file. `printers.conf` is not affected.

Comment: What is the difference between `lp` and `lpr`? I use only `lp`. I don't have any `~/.cups/lpoptions`, only the global `/etc/cups/lpoptions`.

Comment: There's no real difference between `lp` and `lpr` as used with `CUPS`, in short `lp` originated with Unix System V and `lpr` came from the BSD side of the Unix family. Try it with a local lpoptions file, see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I had to do `lpoptions -p <printername> -o cpi=12` for each printer separately. Giving no printer changed it only for the system-wide default printer, but not the others.

Answer (score 1):

Use the lpadmin command (as root):

lpadmin -p printer -o cpi-default=12

This works immediately, a restart of cups is not required.

(The command adds a line to /etc/cups/printers.conf - might take a while before the new line appears there. If you don't want to wait, you can restart cups which updates printers.conf immediately).

Comment: But my question is actually: How do I change it *independent* of the printer? So that it works for **all** printers at once?